# javascript - ".JPG" and ".jpg" for img src

Tags: javascript

I am setting the src attribute of img through javascript like this:

```
var newimgid = "images/" + fldrid + "/" + id + ".jpg";
document.getElementById('slideimg').setAttribute('src',newimgid);
```

This works fine on local, but when I host, ".JPG" and ".jpg" are treated as different, and the ".JPG" images will not load, same with ".JPEG" images.

Why this works on local and not on server?

Comment: normalize your image filenames (make them all `.jpg` so that you don't have any other variants)

Comment: i have hundreds of images, and that would not be a good choice for sure. Thanks!

Comment: The alternatives are worse (such as setting up web server to enumerate all possible filename variants). This one is the only sane thing to do.

Comment: the general way is to turn all extensions to uppercase in scripts so you will know you are dealing with THE extension.

Comment: If your server is under Linux then jpg and JPG are considered as 2 different extensions because linux is case sensitive.

Comment: @user2713781 Why not? Changing hundreds of filenames is as simple as running a single command in the terminal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks everyone. This worked for me..

```
var newimgid = "images/" + fldrid + "/" + id + ".jpg";
document.getElementById('img1').setAttribute('src',newimgid);

img1.onerror = function()
               { var newimgid = "images/" + fldrid + "/" + id + ".JPG"; 
                 document.getElementById('img1').setAttribute('src',newimgid); };
```

Any other way??

Comment: How about `.JPEG` and `.jpeg` files, though?

Comment: similar piece of code for jpeg also. .jpeg were too rare in my case, so I added "onerror" for jpeg inside the first onerror.

Comment: Why don't you just rename the files, again? It's several commands, at most. Probably can be done with a single command, even.

Comment: the thing is that I wanted the client to be able to add images with any format and handled automatically and not force him to convert them to jpg..

Comment: there must be a better way.. just hoping for the answers

Comment: Don't make clients rename files, it's you who should rename files (right after upload, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely locally you use Windows as OS, while on the server you use Linux. Windows is not case sensitive, while Linux is. So image.jpg and image.JPG can exist one next to each other in Linux, but in Windows they cannot. To fix your issue, you need to actually fix either the files on the file system or reference them properly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the windows system locally for development. Windows is not case sensitive and it treats **.jpg** & **.JPG** or **.jpeg** & **.JPEG** as a same image. But when you host the application on Linux (which treats file names case sensitive) assume both files differently.

The best way is to normalize your file names and not be dependent on the operating system.